# Setting values of additional number column in order not to violate primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, primary-key

I have a table filled in with some values, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(FOREIGN_ID VARCHAR(5), VV VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO TABLE1(FOREIGN_ID, VV) VALUES ('I1', 'XXXXX');
INSERT INTO TABLE1(FOREIGN_ID, VV) VALUES ('I2', 'YYYYY');
INSERT INTO TABLE1(FOREIGN_ID, VV) VALUES ('I2', 'ZZZZZ');
INSERT INTO TABLE1(FOREIGN_ID, VV) VALUES ('I2', 'SSSSS');
INSERT INTO TABLE1(FOREIGN_ID, VV) VALUES ('I2', 'SSSSS');
INSERT INTO TABLE1(FOREIGN_ID, VV) VALUES ('I1', 'TTTTT');

FOREIGN_ID  VV
----- ---------
I1   XXXXX
I2   YYYYY
I2   ZZZZZ
I2   SSSSS
I2   SSSSS
I1   TTTTT
```

And I want to add a new column and make it a part of a primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD SEQ_NUMBER NUMBER(5) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE1_PK PRIMARY KEY (FOREIGN_ID, SEQ_NUMBER);
```

Of course, the value 0 of  SEQ_NUMBER and repeated values of   FOREIGN_ID will violate the primary key. How (using Oracle SQL) to set SEQ_NUMBER to 0, 1, 2, ... for each value of  SEQ_NUMBER before the constraint is added?

The result could look like this:

```
FOREIGN_ID  VV  SEQ_NUMBER
----- --------- -----
I1   XXXXX     0
I2   YYYYY     0
I2   ZZZZZ     1
I2   SSSSS     2
I2   SSSSS     3
I1   TTTTT     1
```

Comment: Can there be duplicate data like the 2 rows for I2 - SSSSS? You could execute an UPDATE statement right after adding the SEQ_NUMBER column, to update the SEQ_NUMBER values. Is there is a specific sorting order?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number` analytic function to compute the rank:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by t.foreign_id order by t.vv) - 1 seq_number
from TABLE1 t;
```

This gives the expected result:

```
FOREIGN_ID  VV  SEQ
I1  TTTTT   0
I1  XXXXX   1
I2  SSSSS   0
I2  SSSSS   1
I2  YYYYY   2
I2  ZZZZZ   3
```

Now there is a problem with analytic functions: you can only use them in `select` and `group by` clauses because they are computed at the end. This means that you cannot do what you would like to do, i.e.:

```
update TABLE1 t
set t.seq_number = row_number() over (partition by t.foreign_id order by t.vv)-1
;
```

The best workaround I can think of is to create another table from this one:

```
create table TABLE2 as
select t.foreign_id,
       t.vv,
       row_number() over (partition by t.foreign_id order by t.vv) - 1 seq_number
from TABLE1 t;
```

Then you can apply the PK on this one !

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE2 ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE2_PK PRIMARY KEY (FOREIGN_ID, SEQ_NUMBER);
```